# OnItemClickListener With OnItemLongClickListener

Tags: android

how can i use both OnItemClickListener and OnItemLongClickListener or just disable longclick on a list view?
i've override OnItemLongClickListener  and when i return true on onItemLongClick the longclick will disable but OnItemClickListener wont respond anymore.

```
DailyReportList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){ 
        @Override   
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView parentView, View childView, int position, long id) {

        return true;}});


    registerForContextMenu(DailyReportList);
    DailyReportList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            arg1.showContextMenu();
            FillTxtWithListItems(arg1);

        }});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to disable onClick or onLongClick you just need to uncheck/check the feature in your `layout xml properties`. Find the image on how it can be disabled..[image]

[image]

Comment: Ty for the answer but it doesn't work, i've puted 'android:longClickable="false" to my list layout attribute but it's already longclickable

Comment: you need to remove the code from your Activity, if not then it will behave like you overridden the property

Comment: it's the soloution but it doesn't work for me,anyway appreciate your help and time

Comment: if you got your question answered then accept the answer so that people in the community will find it useful.

Comment: this doesn't solve the issue and my problem but i upvoted it because it's right and would be helpful for someone! my question as i've mentioned on top is how can i override both onlick and onlongclicklistener

Comment: huh .! You asked to disable longclick/click so I posted this answer, can you be more specific as what exactly you want ?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want long click listener nor context menu just do not set any and do not call `registerForContextMenu()`. Lists do not have these by themselves.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i've implemented codes for ContextMenu and it works perfect with onItemclick,just i want to disable longclick on my listItems.